# Excel VBA ADO SQL connection error - Could not find the object

Tags: vba, excel, ado

I got a brilliant answer to my previous question from @Ryan Wildry but I thought I'd ask a different question regarding the same code: here goes.

### Background Info

I have a shared (network/server) Excel template file which is both the input file and the data source (although on different sheets). Let's call that `Input.xltm`.

The code basically picks up a input in a range on `Input Sheet`, takes the first two letters and finds the closest code from `Code Sheet`, then populates a UserForm ListBox with the top five results.

### The problem

The problem comes when users set off the UserForm and the error usually returns:

**`Run-time error '-2147467259' 
The Microsoft Access database engine could not find the object 'C:\Users\user.name\Documents\Input1'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.......etc`**

I think it **may have something to do with the fact Excel puts a number after the filename because it's a template file** although I don't actually know!

### The code

And here's the code:

```
Public MyConnection As New ADODB.Connection
Public MyRecordset  As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim ColumnName As String: ColumnName = "[Variant code]"
Dim SearchStr  As String: SearchStr = Left(Sheets("Input Sheet").Range("B4").Value2, 2)
Dim dbstring As String

dbstring = ThisWorkbook.FullName

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If MyConnection.State <> adStateOpen Then
    With MyConnection
        .ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbstring & _
                            ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1';"
        .Open
    End With
End If

If MyRecordset.State = adStateOpen Then MyRecordset.Close
MyRecordset.Open "Select top 5 " & ColumnName & " from [Code Sheet$] where " & ColumnName & _
                 " like '%" & SearchStr & "%'", MyConnection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly

Me.ListBox1.Clear
If Not MyRecordset.EOF Then MyRecordset.MoveFirst

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Do Until MyRecordset.EOF
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem MyRecordset.Fields(0).Value
    MyRecordset.MoveNext
Loop

End Sub
```

I just need everyone who accesses the file through the server to be able to pick up the correct data source (which is only in the next sheet) and populate the ListBox.

I'd be thankful for any suggestions! Thanks

### #UPDATE

I have checked, now **if you open (and then save) the actual template file so there's no '1' after the file name, then the code works as expected.** It's only when the template is opened normally and the number automatically appended that it stops working.

Comment: AFAIK you need to be working with a workbook that exists on the filesystem before you can connect to it.  So that implies you can connect to the original xlst file, or you can connect to something based on it **after** you have saved it once.  So you could possibly just hardcode the name of the xlst file in `dbstring = "putXLSTFilenameHere"`.

Comment: @YowE3K Thanks - I get a different error now, "External table is not in the expected format" ! Would I have to reference the sheet as well?

Comment: If you are telling it to look in the XLST file, you will need to reference the sheet that contains the data in the XLST file, i.e. change `[Code Sheet$]` to whatever the sheet is in the XLST file.  (Disclaimer:  I have never used a template file, so I am just assuming that they are in the same format as a normal xlsx file, i.e. have sheets, etc, with sheet names, etc.)

Comment: @YowE3K - It's actually XLTM but yes, obviously it's all one file so the `[Cost Sheet]` does not need to change, I was referring to the Data Source where I've now hardcoded the filename into the `dbstring`. Putting `Input.xltm!Cost Sheet` returns the old error again, what should I use?? Thanks

Comment: It should be just something like "X:\pathOnServer\Input.xltm" (assuming "X" is the network drive), i.e. the full filename including drive and path.  (And I just worked out that it was xltm instead of xlst when I went to save a test workbook and couldn't find a xlst option to save it as - I warned you that I had never used one before!  LOL)

Comment: My apologies, I did use the full path, (N:\Path\Input.xltm), yet it's still rejecting it - not in the expected format. LOL :)

Comment: I'm out of my depth then.  If I get a chance I'll keep playing (I'm getting similar error messages) but hopefully someone else with more experience will help you out.

Comment: One thing I should ask - would it be an acceptable workaround to just stick the table you are referring to in a normal xlsx file stored alongside the xltm file, and then refer to the xlsx file each time?

Comment: @YowE3K, Maybe but it pulls from an SQL source and everything's already set up round that.... so yes, that would have been a good solution but..! Thanks..

Comment: I was thinking that you could change the dbstring to a known, already saved, xlsx file - i.e. `dbstring = "putXLSXFilenameHere"`.  As far as I can tell, the problems are occurring because of some difference between xlsx and xltm files, but I can't find a connection string change to allow for the difference.  (But I can find references to other people having issues accessing xltm files.)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you do not make early-binding for `MyConnection` and `MyRecordset` first.

You can make a late-binding by

## step 1.

Change

```
Public MyConnection As New ADODB.Connection
Public MyRecordset  As New ADODB.Recordset
```

to

```
Public MyConnection As object
Public MyRecordset  As object
```

.

## step 2.

Add

```
Set MyConnection = createobject("adodb.connection")
Set MyRecordset = createobject("adodb.recordset")
```

before `If MyConnection.State <> adStateOpen Then`

Comment: What is the err msg?  And Where does it stop?

Comment: As before; Run-time error, ..... could not find the object....... Input1 (note no file extension and it's pulling from my Documents, not the server path of the template file)

Comment: It just won't Show the UserForm, so it stops Initializing when it can't find the object. **See update above**